# Binding data to textarea inside the Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have one Gridview inside I have three columns like

```
ID              Name                Message
Chkbox          New                 Textarea
Chkbox          Closed              Textarea
Chkbox          Pending             Textarea
```

Q.I have to bind data to this Gridview with chkeck box checked and the respected texarea text.
I have put textarea inside the `<TemplateField HeaderText="Message"><ItemTemplate><textarea id="txtArMsg">`
How could I bind the Text to this texarea and checked the respected check box.

Comment: @Brissles Yes its in Asp.Net Web

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `TemplateField` and a `TextBox` (rather than Textarea) for the text column:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="YourTextColumn">
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("your_text_database_field") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>    
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And a `CheckBoxField` for your `CheckBox` column:

```
<asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="YourCheckBoxColumn" DataField="your_boolean_database_field"/>
```

Replace `your_text_database_field` and `your_boolean_database_field` with your corresponding database field names.